# JsqMessageViewController view only showing single line texts

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am currently using JSQMessageViewController and filling it with data from a firebase table - I followed the Fire-chat example available on Firebase's site. Everything is working except for some reason the cells are only showing the first line of a multi-line text, and then cutting it off.

I pretty much followed what is https://github.com/firebase/ios-swift-chat-example

My incoming/ outgoing bubble views are instantiated in my viewdidload

```
self.incomingBubble = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory().incomingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(CHAT_GRAY_COLOR)
```

And the cells are filled from my messages array

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
    return self.messages[indexPath.item]
}
```

And then there are a lot of required JSQCollectionView methods, including:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageBubbleImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource! {
    let message = messages[indexPath.item]

    if message.senderId() == sender {
        return outgoingBubble
    }

    return incomingBubble

}
```

If anyone has run into this before I'd greatly appreciate any help. I'll keep scouring the documentation in the mean time

Will

Answer (score 1):

Check your `Message object`. The height of the bubble is determined by the `Message.Hash` so if you created your own message object that inherits for `JSQMessage` make sure you are setting the hash its as simple as

`func messageHash() -> UInt {
        return UInt(self.hash)
    }`

But if you are implementing your messages like normal I.E.

`JSQMessage(senderId: AvatarIdCook, displayName: DisplayNameCook, text: "What is this Black Majic?")`

then you should not have this issue. let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with constraints, after you're done downloading the data from Firebase, do you add this?

```
self.finishReceivingMessageAnimated(true)
```

Comment: Yup I have the call to finishReceivingMessageAnimated after downloading the data. Do you know more about where the constraints for JSQMessageViewCells would be? I'll take a loot at that